# Fast general method to calculate percentiles

Tags: postgresql, statistics

I want to find n>1 percentiles of an unsorted column in PostgreSQL. For example the 20th, 40th, 60th, 80th and 100th percentile.

An obvious solution is to count and sort the column and then do a look but I'm hoping for a better solution. Any ideas?

P.S. I have found a good [solution](http://forge.mysql.com/tools/tool.php?id=149) for MySQL but can't translate it to psql

Comment: Have you considered [windowing functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-window.html), eg cume_dist()?

Comment: Postgres has PERCENT_RANK()

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have come up with the following:

```
select cume, max(var) AS max_var
from (
   select var
        , ntile(5) over (order by var) as cume
   from table
   ) as tmp
group by cume
order by cume;
```

It selects the maximum of each group that is divided using [`ntile()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE).